# Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04 cannot connect to the internet

Tags: 12.04, firefox

Every other browser installed is working fine, but Firefox will not connect to the internet. What do I need to check to make Firefox work on my computer? I am new to Ubuntu. I searched the web, but could not find enough clear information.

This is the error message that I am getting just before launching the application:

> Could not initialize the application's security component. The most
>   likely cause is problems with files in your application's profile
>   directory. Please check that this directory has no read/write
>   restrictions and your hard disk is not full or close to full. It is
>   recommended that you exit the application and fix the problem. If you
>   continue to use this session, you might see incorrect application
>   behaviour when accessing security features.

Comment: what happens if you do `sudo firefox` in a terminal?

Comment: It got installed successfully, but when I try to launch the application showing the above error

Answer (score 1):

1. [Reset your firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems) The reset feature works by creating a new profile folder for you while saving your:Bookmarks,Browsing history,Passwords,Cookies,Web form auto-fill information.**Your original will be lost**.
2. [Troubleshooting](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/couldnt-initialize-applications-security-component) by yourself for a long time

**EDIT**
Use safemode,choose reset button

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

or Use profile manager，type in terminal:

```
firefox -p
```

Comment: He can't start Firefox, so he'll never be able to reset it by the way showed on your link.

Comment: @Farid What about `firefox -safe-mode`?

Comment: Hey Thanks Zhang Yuan..! It is not solved my problem..drived me towards solving the problem..! Thank you..Now I resolved the issue..!I would have vote up but I don have enough reputation

Comment: @Chella,I'm willing to hear that you solve your problem.We are appreciate that if you can post your approaches.

Comment: 1.I tried your advice "firefox -safe-mode" first(problem not solved)
2. then I typed firefox alone..! It asked me to reset the firefox completely, I chosen reset, restarted Firefox-> problem solved..!
earlier I restarted firefox but not reset'ed